# Import values from a CSV file into one cell array

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a .dat file similar to the following:

```
* ID=Minilog-T
* Serial Number=1328
* Study ID=Rostherne 2008
* Start Time=13-11-2008,14:23:14
* Finish Time=09-12-2009,13:01:53
* Sample Period=02:00:00
* Number of Deployments=9
* Date(dd-mm-yyyy),Time(hh:mm:ss),Celsius (°C)
13-11-2008,14:23:14,20.6
13-11-2008,16:23:14,15.3
```

I would like to insert the data into a cell array where I have:

```
dat = {'13-11-2008','14:23:14','20.6';'13-11-2008','16:23:14','15.3'};

dat = 

    '13-11-2008'    '14:23:14'    '20.6'
    '13-11-2008'    '16:23:14'    '15.3'
```

I have tried:

```
fid = fopen(...);
dat = textscan(fid,'%s%s%s','headerlines',8);
```

However, this imports everything into 3 separate cell arrays i.e. it does not take the same format as a matrix. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that `textscan` puts each extracted column in its own cell, so a slightly different approach is required.

One possible way to do it would involve using `textscan` to extract the relevant lines, and then splitting each one into comma-delimited strings using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html):

```
dat = textscan(fid, '%s', 'headerlines', 8, 'delimiter', '\n')
C = regexp(dat{1}, ',', 'split');
dat = vertcat(C{:})
```